# How can I make a Bum Rush easier?

Tags: final-fantasy-6

Sabin's special technique is "Blitz"; which does a high amount of damage if fighting-game style commands are executed correctly.  The Bum Rush - Sabin's most damaging Blitz - requires a full 360° trip around the control pad.  Is there any way to make this Blitz easier to execute?

Comment: We were [just discussing this the other day](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7880578#7880578) as a matter of fact...

Comment: In my experience, the Bum Rush doesn't have to be done particularly *fast*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes!  You can blitz easily with Sabin by **only pressing the cardinal directions** - you don't need to make a full circle or push the diagonals, just tap the directions in order, and he will do the blitz just as well.

The [Final Fantasy Wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Blitz_(Final_Fantasy_VI)) says that you must tap Left, Left, Up, Up, Right, Right, Down, Down, Left.

Also note that it doesn't matter which way Sabin is facing (ie, if you are in a back attack or pincer attack, where he might be on the left rather than the right) - the directions are always the same.

Comment: I apparently remembered this wrong, I originally thought you could do it by tapping Left, Up, Right, Down, Left, which is not the case :P

Comment: Where the heck were you with this information 18 years ago?

Comment: @Brant, I know, right?!?  I didn't know about this until I played the GBA version.  I broke my thumbs on the SNES and PS1 versions :(